# Apply on Message resolves MessageName before applying

Tags: expression-manipulation, hold, usage-messages

I want to make a `Message` from a `List`.

```
Message[LibraryFunction::argx, 1, 3]
```

> LibraryFunction::argx: 1 called with 3 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

```
Apply[Message, Flatten[List[MessageName[LibraryFunction, "argx"], {2, 3}]]]
```

> LibraryFunction::argx: 2 called with 3 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

After I define the `MessageName` it works fine with `Message`.

```
LibraryFunction::argx = "called with `1` argument(s) `2` argument(s) is expected."
Message[LibraryFunction::argx, 1, 3]
```

> LibraryFunction::argx: called with 1 argument(s) 3 argument(s) is expected.

However with `Apply` it first deduces `MessageName` to string.

```
Apply[Message, Flatten[List[MessageName[LibraryFunction, "argx"], {2, 3}]]]
```

> Message::name: Message name called with `1` argument(s) `2` argument(s) is expected. is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.
>
> ```
> Message["called with `1` argument(s) `2` argument(s) is expected.", 2, 3]
> ```

What should I do such that the message is shown properly with `Apply`?

**UPDATE**

Kuba's answer works in general most of the time. However I have loaded a library with `LibraryFunctionLoad`

```
SomeFunctionWX = LibraryFunctionLoad["/path/to/libmod02.so", "SomeFunctionWX", LinkObject, LinkObject]
SomeFunctionWX::argx = "hallo `1` `2`"
Message[SomeFunctionWX::argx, 2, 3]
```

> SomeFunctionWX::argx: hallo 2 3

Everything works if I use `Message` but when I use the `Apply` based method in the answer it breaks

```
Apply[Message[MessageName[#, #2], ##3] &, Flatten[{SomeFunctionWX, "argx", {2, 3}}]]
```

> Message::name: Message name MessageName[LibraryFunction[/path/to/libmod02.so,SomeFunctionWX,LinkObject],argx] is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.

It evaluates `SomeFunctionWX` to LibraryFunction

**UPDATE**

The following worked.

```
Message[MessageName[SomeFunctionWX, "argx"], {2, 3} /. List -> Sequence]
```

Comment: In your edit, `SomeFunctionWX` evaluates to something else.  Is there a reason why you want associate this symbol with a message?  One could hack something together to make this work, but it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: As the function name is `SomeFunctionWX` it seems logical to see messages like `SomeFunctionWX::rankerr`

Comment: Usually when we say the function's name is `f`, `f` by itself won't evaluate to anything.  Perhaps it would make more sense for you to define something like `SomeFunctionWX[args___] := LibraryFunctionLoad["/path/to/libmod02.so", "SomeFunctionWX", LinkObject, LinkObject][args]`.  You could even use a trick to make the LibraryFunctionLoad evaluate only once -- `With[{lfl=LibraryFunctionLoad["/path/to/libmod02.so", "SomeFunctionWX", LinkObject, LinkObject]}, SomeFunctionWX[args___]:=lfl[args] ]`.

Comment: But then the function name wouldn't evaluate before you try to apply Message/ MessageName to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Message` is `HoldFirst` in order to handle `MessageName` well. You need to prevent `MessageName` from evaluation. It may be use case dependent but here is how I'd approach it:

```
Apply[
  Message[MessageName[#, #2], ##3] &,
  Flatten[{LibraryFunction, "argx", {2, 3}}]
]
```

This way you can manipulate name and arguments in the second line without worrying about `MessageName` evaluation etc.

Comment: I have loaded a library with `SomeFunctionWX = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad["libmod02.so",  "SomeFunctionWX", LinkObject, LinkObject]` then `Message[SomeFunctionWX::argx, 2, 3]` works but `Apply[Message[MessageName[#, #2], ##3] &, 
 Flatten[{SomeFunctionWX, "argx", {2, 3}}]]` does not

Comment: Please Check Edit

Comment: @NeelBasu where do you get `Flatten[{SomeFunctionWX, "argx", {2, 3}}]` from? Could you give a little bit of context so I can address your use case well?

Comment: I can send you the output in a few hours. I have the placeholder values in a `List` from there I am constructing the `Message`. I first tried to solve this using a List and then `Apply`. Actually this is for the library Mathematica++ that I am working on. Currently I have changed the storage from `List` to `Sequence` and things are working. But still I am curious in general how can I build it from list. In Mathematica++ I can append inside a sequence so this worked. However in general Append don't work on `List`.

Comment: I think possibly if we change the head from list to sequence then it might work.

Comment: It gives `{LibraryFunction[ "/home/neel/Projects/mathematicapp/build/examples/libmod03.so", "SomeFunctionWX", {Real, Integer}, Real], "argx", 2, 3}`. Now the problem is resolved.

Comment: Since you can directly write `Message[MessageName[SomeFunctionWX, "argx"]..` it makes the task a lot simpler. But then why do you need `{2, 3} /. List -> Sequence`? Can't `2, 3` be put there directly? It is hard to help without knowing what you have control on and what not.

Comment: `{2, 3}` are stored as `List` prior sending the `Message`